# Complexity of itertools.permutations

Tags: python, time-complexity

Can you please tell me what is the complexity of `permutations()` from the "itertools.permutation" module in python?

I am practicing and learning python, and appreciate any help from you.

Comment: You'd have to study the [C source code for the object](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e106d9368bff/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l2527).

Answer (score 0):

It's O(1), because it just returns an object whose `next` method returns a different permutation each time it is called. The size of the argument to `permutations` does not affect the time it takes to create that object.